# Como obtener documentos de firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Me estoy iniciando con React y Firebase. Me gustaría saber como podría obtener datos cada uno los diferentes documentos que hay en mi colección y no sólo todos a la vez.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO], por favor compartenos el código que llevas hasta el momento para poder ayudarte. Revisa [ask]

Comment: Muéstranos cómo está estructurada tu base de datos (aquí se admite una captura de pantalla) y el texto del código que estás intentando. Si hay algún error agrégalo también. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.